# Firebase Flame plan: what is the limitation and quota for firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, quota

I'm looking for information about the limitation and quota for **Firebase Flame Plan.**
However, I couldn't find any official reference for that.

It seems they no longer recommend use of Flame plan since there seemed to be few users of it.

I found some comments saying the quota for **Firestore Read is 250k/day**.

However one of my projects using Flame plan exceeds 250k limitation way over and still working.

It's about 10m reads so far only for April.

**Can anyone provide the information about the quota for firestore in Flame plan?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), there is no more Flame plan.  In the [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq) it states:

> As of January 2020, the Flame billing plan ($25/mo of additional
>   quota) is no longer available for new sign-ups.
>
> - Existing Spark and Blaze plan projects and any new projects can no longer switch to or sign up for the Flame plan.
> - If you move an existing Flame plan project to a different billing plan, the project cannot return to the Flame plan.
> - Existing Flame plan projects can continue to use the Flame plan for now. However, you'll receive information in the coming months about
>     the required timeline for moving to another billing plan.

If you have further questions about the Flame plan, [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: Thank you for the information. The thing was that that information was not in japanese FAQ page.
I found the quota information.

Cloud Firestore
Data storage 2.5 GiB total
Network egress 20 GiB/month
Document writes 100k/day
Document reads 250k/day
Document deletes 100k/day

Comment: However, I'm still unclear of why my app still working after exceeding the daily quota of firestore read. Do you have any idea?

Comment: As I said, contact Firebase support.